# I can only add a new cell to a collection View Controller through prepareforSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, unwind-segue

I am trying to add a new cell to my `collectionViewController` after another controller adds an additional element to the array which serves as the data source for the view controller. Ive been told that it is wrong to do it this way but the only way that I can get the `collectionViewController` to add a new cell is if I call `insertItems(at: [indexPath])` in the `prepareForSegue` function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToCollectionView"{
        let CVC = segue.destination as! CollectionViewController
        if let image = image{
        CVC.images.insert(imagePost(image:image), at: 0)
            print("Image is not nil")
        }
        let index = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
         CVC.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [index])
        print("In prepare for segue: \(CVC.images.count)")
    }
```

Is this the wrong way to add a new cell, what would be the correct way to implement what I am trying to achieve here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a wrong way , but you better try to make the array global and add items to it everywhere you want and whenever the main VC appear in viewDidAppear reload the collection

Answer (score 0):

If you have `CustomCollectionViewController` and `AddToArrayViewController`, create a delegate protocol `AddToArrayViewControllerDelegate`, with a delegate method `addToArrayViewController(viewController: didAdd:)`.

Whenever your `AddToArrayViewController` adds something, you call your `addToArrayViewController(viewController: didAdd:)` delegate call.

Make sure `CustomCollectionViewController` implements `AddToArrayViewControllerDelegate`, and then whenever the `didAdd` call is made, you can add the item to the array, and reload the CollectionView.